# Configuring KnpPaginatorBundle manually without internet connection

Tags: php, symfony-2.4, knppaginator

I require setting the package in a disconnected environment. I have read some special web sites that talks about it, but in previous versions.

I'm using Symfony 2.4.1, recently downloaded.
The KnpPaginatorBundle package I downloaded today exactly.

I extracted the **master.zip**, with this folder inside: "KnpPaginatorBundle-master", from GitHub repository and assumed this structure:

```
 \vendor\Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle
```

[image]

### I received this error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "KnpPaginatorBundle" from namespace "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle" in C:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\sf_zktime\app\AppKernel.php line 20. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

### This is the line 20 in App_Kernel.php:

```
new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),//Paginator
```

### This is my local path in vendors packages:

```
C:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\sf_zktime\vendor\Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle
```

### This is my config.yml parameters:

```
knp_paginator:
  page_range: 5 # número de páginas que se muestran en el paginador

  default_options:
    # los siguientes tres parámetros permiten "traducir" el paginador
    # puedes utilizar por ejemplo: 'pagina', 'ordenar' y 'direccion'
    page_name:           page
    sort_field_name:     sort
    sort_direction_name: direction

    # sólo incluir resultados diferentes (útil cuando haces consultas GROUP BY)
    distinct: true

  template:
    # estas opciones configuran la plantilla utilizada para la paginación
    # y para los controles que premiten reordenar los resultados
    pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig
    sortable:   KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig
```

### It's a mix between these references:

http://symfony.es/bundles/knplabs/knppaginatorbundle/instalacion-en-symfony-2-1
https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/

Comment: Check your `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` for the line `'Knp\\Bundle\\PaginatorBundle' => array(...`. The offline way is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` and add this line:

```
'Knp\\Bundle\\PaginatorBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle'),
```

EDIT: Move your plugin folder to `vendor/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle/`, so now the real path would be: `vendor/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle/Knp/Bundle/PaginatorBundle/`.

Then delete cache and reload the web server.

Comment: I did the last thing you suggested, but console gave this error when trying to clean cache up: 
C:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\sf_zktime\app>php console cache:clear
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle' not found in C:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\sf_zktime\ap
p\AppKernel.php on line 21.

Comment: Check the edited answer, put the plugin root inside the folder I specified.

Comment: I'll do that, but why do I need to add additional folder levels, I saw several vendor packages that function the same manner. Is there any logic cause?

Comment: The `/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle` part is the contanier folder, that can be anything, the rest of the path is the actual namespace, that's why you can't put it right in `vendor/`.

Comment: The issue disappeared, but it threw other exception unknown for me: ReflectionException: Class Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Paginate\PaginationSubscriber does not exist

Comment: @Félix told you the offline way was gonna be bumpy. Check this https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/59  To avoid future issues just do it online with composer the first time and then go offline for development, composer is a breeze compared to this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` and add this line:

```
'Knp\\Component' => array($vendorDir . '/knplabs/knp-components/src'),
'Knp\\Bundle\\PaginatorBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle'),
```

its work for me

regards..

Hendrawan

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1) In cmd run:
   composer require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle

2) In autoload_namespaces add:
   'Knp\Component' => array($vendorDir . '/knplabs/knp-components/src'),

3) In config.yml:

```
 knp_paginator:
     page_range: 5 # number of pages displayed in the paginator.

     default_options:
        # the following three parameters allow "translate" the paginator.
        # you can use eg 'page', 'order' and 'direction'
        page_name:           page
        sort_field_name:     sort
        sort_direction_name: direction

        # only include different results (useful when you do GROUP BY 
        #  queries)                   
        distinct: true

    template:
        # these options configure the template used for pagination.
        # and the controls that allow you to sort the results
        pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig
        sortable:   KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig
```

4) In Appkernel.php add:
            new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),

5) In a cmd run:
            php app/console cache:clear

6) Reload browser.

7) Finally, it works !